# Initializing an object property to the value of another object property in DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm attempting to bind two objects (List LedgerEntries and List BuyerSellers) to a single DataGridView.  LedgerEntry contains a property for Buyer_Seller, and I would like the end-user to select a Buyer_Seller from a combobox (populated by the BuyerSellers generic collection) in the DataGridView and the LedgerEntries string BuyerSeller property be set to the Buyer_Seller string Name property.

At the moment I'm only using one BindingSource and I'm not defining my own columns; they are auto-generated based on the object being bound to the DGV.  Where I'm a little lost is how to ensure the property in one object is initialized to the value of the combobox that's populated by another object.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found what I was looking for here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/62ddde6c-ed96-4696-a5d4-ef52e32ccbf7/binding-of-datagridviewcomboboxcolumn-when-using-object-binding

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    List<LedgerEntry> ledgerEntries = new List<LedgerEntry>();
    List<Address> addresses = new List<Address>();
    BindingSource entrySource = new BindingSource();
    BindingSource adSource = new BindingSource();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        entrySource.DataSource = ledgerEntries;
        adSource.DataSource = addresses;

        DataGridViewComboBoxColumn adr = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
        adr.DataPropertyName = "Address";
        adr.DataSource = adSource;
        adr.DisplayMember = "OrganizationName";
        adr.HeaderText = "Organization";
        adr.ValueMember = "Ref";

        ledger.Columns.Add(adr);
        ledger.DataSource = entrySource;

        addresses.Add(new Address("Test1", "1234", 5678));
        addresses.Add(new Address("Test2", "2345", 9876));
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (LedgerEntry le in ledgerEntries)
            MessageBox.Show(le.Address.OrganizationName + " // " + le.Description);
    }
}

public class LedgerEntry
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public string OrganizationName { get; set; }
    public string StreetAddress { get; set; }
    public int ZipCode { get; set; }

    public Address(string orgname, string addr, int zip)
    {
        OrganizationName = orgname;
        StreetAddress = addr;
        ZipCode = zip;
    }

    public Address Ref
    {
        get { return this; }
        set { Ref = value; }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.OrganizationName;
    }
}
```